# AngularJS adding input value to $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
<input id="width" name="width" style="width:100px" type="text" ng-model="width">
```

How would I get the value from above to write into the $scope under `$scope.user.width` when there is no default value?

Comment: Change it to ng-model='user.width' and it updates automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your need to have `user.width` in your html

```
<input id="width" name="width" style="width:100px" type="text" ng-model="user.width">
```

This is assuming that your `controller` is constructed like this:

```
$scope.user = {
    width: '',
    height: '',
}
```

You can even put a default value there instead of just setting it to an empty string.